# Why is completeness of measures important?

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone give an example why a non-complete measure is a problem? Or what are some theorems that require a measure to be complete?

Comment: my area of studies uses stochastic processes. I just asked http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539733/measurability-question-with-regard-to-a-stochastic-process See if you understand this.

Comment: The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure) provides a motivation for a measure to be complete.

Comment: Without completeness, your theorems would have to refer to sets that are subsets of measure 0. That's awkward.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147381/why-do-we-essentially-need-complete-measure-space

Comment: Thank you all for the quick answers. @Lost1, I have studied stochastic processes but I need a very intense revision to relearn all the definitions that I have forgotten in your example.

Comment: @julien, the problem with that example at the wikipedia page is that it is just the monotonicity of measures but applied to two dimensional cases.